# CorrelationTest small bug?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Consider two Normally distributed random variables:

```
x1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {1000}];
x2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {1000}];
```

I want to test $H_0 : \rho = 0$ against $H_1 : \rho \neq 0$.

If I use

```
CorrelationTest[Transpose[{x1, x2}], 0, {"TestDataTable", All}]
```

I get, for instance,

> \begin{array}{l|ll}
>  \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  \text{Pearson Correlation} & 0.00505234 & 0.873251 \\
>  \text{Spearman Rank} & 0.00983509 & 0.756138 \\
> \end{array}

However, if I use

```
PearsonCorrelationTest[x1, x2, "TestDataTable"]
```

I get

> \begin{array}{l|ll}
>  \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  \text{Pearson Correlation} & 0.00505234 & 0.87322 \\
> \end{array}

and, finally, if I use

```
SpearmanRankTest[x1, x2, "TestDataTable"]
```

I get

> \begin{array}{l|ll}
>  \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  \text{Spearman Rank} & 0.00983509 & 0.756081 \\
> \end{array}

Now **compare** the P-Values of the tests... they are slightly different, although they are supposed to be exactly the same test.

Can anyone confirm this? If yes, could it be a small bug in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you check the properties and relations sections of the examples for both `CorrelationTest` and `SpearmanRankTest` you will see that these are not identical tests.

In the first case we are checking whether the correlation coefficient is a particular value and the p-value is computed using a Fisher Z transformation.  This transformation allows us to test against other null values (not just that the `Correlation` or `SpearmanRho` is zero).

In the case of `SpearmanRankTest` it is purely a test of independence (i.e. you cannot test against other null hypotheses) and it is assumed that `ρ Sqrt[(n-2)/(1-ρ^2)]`  follows a `StudentTDistribution`.

**This is not a bug.**

---

**Edit:**

Here is some further evidence that these are testing different hypotheses.

```
v1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
v2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];

SpearmanRankTest[v1, v2, "TestConclusion"]

(* "The null hypothesis that the populations are independent is rejected at the 5 
  percent level based on the Spearman Rank test."*)

CorrelationTest[Transpose[{v1, v2}], 0, {"TestConclusion", "SpearmanRank"}]

(*"The null hypothesis that the population rank correlation coefficient is equal to 0. 
   is rejected at the 5 percent level based on the Spearman Rank test."*)
```

Comment: Could I assume the same for the Pearson correlation test?

Comment: Yes, it is the same for `PearsonCorrelationTest`. Again, you can check the properties and relations section to confirm.

Comment: It seems to me they are testing the same *hypotheses* but are using different approximations to the sampling distribution of the test statistic.

Comment: @whuber in this particular case that is essentially true.  However, that is only because we happen to have set the null value to zero for `CorrelationTest`.